# Regex to extract USER:PASS from mixed user:pass and email:pass

Tags: regex

If I have a file with some lines like this

```
user1:pass1
user2@email.com:pass2
```

and I want to extract that like this one

```
user1:pass1
user2:pass2
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`, you could use the following RegEx:

```
sed -e "s/\(.*\)@.*:\(.*\)/\1:\2/g" input.txt
```

This will generate the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the "pattern" is to remove the `@domain` component from any line that contains it. On systems that have `sed` this command will perform that action on the file called `file`:

```
sed 's/@[^:]*//' file
```

Output using your example as a source

```
user1:pass1
user2:pass2
```